# Re-edit netif_Rx function and up the respective module

Tags: linux, networking, kernel, ethernet

I edit the function netif_rx in the dev.c at the /net/core just to make a printk when a packet arrives.

```
I called "make" at the kernel's root directory but i don't know witch module was compiled. I need to update the old-module ir order to turn on the changes that i made.

If i want to see my changes i need to:

1-make at the kernel's root directory;
2- make modules;
3-make bzImage;
4- insert the new bzImage on the grub file;
5-Reboot;

I want to to access directly to the modulean update withou do all that things.
```

Could you help me.

Best regards,
Ricardo Ribeiro

Comment: You can not, dev.c is built into the main kernel image. You have to recompile the whole kernel if you make changes to it.

What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to capture the packet that go througth that function. I insert a printk to inform everytime that a packet arrives. I recompiled the kernel again and reboot. The changes were made with sucess. I sent packets ethernet to the interface and no print happens, but if i monitor with wireshark, the packets arrived with sucess. What could be the problem?

Comment: I was searching on web for information and i found this: netif_rx still in the file dev.c but isn't use to much. Nowaday the function used to receive the packets is netif_receive_skb. Can you confirm that to me? I didn't find the reason for that yet. Thank you a lot

Comment: If you just want to receive all packets coming in on a particular interface you can also use libpcap or a raw socket. Or is there any particular reason you would like to do it in the kernel?

Comment: The ideia is using the kernel to implement an ethernet switch. Libcap and raw socket can do that. But if i can receive the packet without an high level library,at kernel level, that is nice to real time application. Think i save some time and reduce de latency on communications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get your goal correctly, the simplest you can do is to implement your own kernel module where you register a protocol handler for `ETH_P_ALL` with `dev_add_pack()`. This way you will receive all incoming packets for a particular device (if you also specify `pt->dev`) or all devices (if `pt->dev` is `NULL`).